# Stream of numbers: What is the probability that a number is higher than all previous numbers (as a function of its rank)

Tags: probability

Hypothesis:

- Assume we have a stream of numbers in a known interval, e.g. integers in $[1, 1000]$.
- Let $v_{max}$ be the size of the domain (the count of all distinct numbers in this interval, i.e. $v_{max}=1000$).

Question: What is the probability that a number at position/rank $k$ in the stream is higher than all previous numbers?

Possible solutions:

- Assume we do not know the value of the number at rank k. I believe the probability to be a maximum is $(1/2)^{k-1}$ (the size of the domain does not matter). The idea is that the number has a $50\%$ probability to be bigger than any of the previous numbers. All numbers are independent, therefore the probability that all are smaller than the $k$-th number is $(1/2)^{k-1}$.
- Assume now that we know the value of the $k$-th number (denoted by $v_k$). Following a similar logic as above, the probability becomes now $(v_k/v_{max})^{k-1}$.

Are these statements correct?

Comment: Are these numbers independent and do they have same distribution?

Comment: I assume that the distribution is discrete uniform, say the integers from $1$ to $N$. By higher do you mean really higher, or just $\ge$? Some details will be different if your underlying distribution is continuous uniform.

Comment: Or are these a sample of distinct integers (so the sample size cannot be more than $v_{max}=1000$) ?

Comment: Yes, all numbers are independent, have the same discreet uniform probability to be selected, and can repeat. I was thinking of $>$ but $>=$ is also fine it that makes the problem easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case: You have $k$ numbers.  The highest is equally likely to be first, second, third, ..., $k$th.  So the probability is $1/k$ that the last one is highest.
$a>b$ and $a>c$ are not independent.  $a>b$ makes $a>c$ more likely.  Try it out with just those three numbers.  There are six options: a>b>c,a>c>b,b>a>c,b>c>a,c>a>b,c>b>a.

Comment: Your answer is correct in case that one don't know any of numbers and one wants to know the probability of the fact that the maximum is on the last place. But if one know first $k-1$ numbers, the probability that $k$-th number is bigger than any previous is different.

Comment: This ignores the possibility that some of the numbers might be equal. Note that the OP's example distribution is discrete...

Comment: So the chance that $v_k$ is greater than the others is $((v_k-1)/v_{max})^{k-1}$

Comment: If all numbers are different, it would be ${v_k-1\choose k-1}/{v_{max}-1\choose k-1}$

Comment: I did a quick simulation and I can confirm what Michael said: $1/k$ is the correct probability assuming we do not know the k-th number. I think this also means that, for the case where we know the k-th number, that $((v_k-1) / v_{max})^{k-1}$ is incorrect.

Comment: @user2066248: $1/k$ is correct if the integers *must* be distinct, which leads to the ${v_k-1\choose k-1}/{v_{max}-1\choose k-1}$ result if you know $v_k$.

Comment: Henry, thanks for the answer. Let me summarize the answers: Case 1: $v_k$ not known, numbers repeat -- the probability is $1/k$ (verified this numerically). Case 2: $v_k$ not known, numbers cannot repeat -- probability is still $1/k$. Case 3: $v_k$ known, numbers repeat -- probability is $((v_k-1)/v_{max})^{k-1}$. Case 4: $v_k$ known, numbers do not repeat -- probability is ${v_{k}−1} \choose {k−1}$ /${{v_{max}−1} \choose {k−1}}$

Comment: PS: I will verify all of these numerically. Several things bother me: a) the $1/k$ probability does not seem to depend on whether the number repeat or not; b) the logic I see behind the probability formulas is different each time (although all reasonings seem sound); c) there should be some form of equivalence between the probabilities when $v_k$ is known. Assume for example $v_{max} >> v_k, k$ => we can apply Euler's limit for Case 3 and get $p \approx e^{-k({v_{max} - v_k})/v_{max}} \approx e^{-k}$. Would this mean that the probability formula in Case 4 should have the same limit?